# Cannot build in .NET 7 when referencing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I was trying to upgrade a couple of NuGet packages in my C# ASP.NET Core application, including **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices 8.0.0**.

I cannot compile with this NuGet. At least not with .NET 7.0. It fails with this error message:

> Startup.cs(18,18): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous
> between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsBuilderExtensions.Validat
> eOnStart(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsBuilder)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjectio
> n.OptionsBuilderExtensions.ValidateOnStart(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsBuilder)'

The code line it complains about looks like this:

```
services.AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection(MyOptions.Name))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

I have tried to rewrite this to call the method in **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsBuilderExtensions** explicitly. That did not help. I haven't found any workaround that lets me compile this against .NET 7.0.

Here is a minimal working example that shows the failure: https://github.com/CAP-3Shape/Logging.AzureAppServices

project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>CA1805,CA1812,CS1573,CS1591,CS8002,TS1009</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: All information should be in the question itself ... Without project file Guru Stron's answer exits without context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the dependency to `7.0.14`:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices --version 7.0.14
```

The `8.0.0` version [depends on](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices#dependencies-body-tab) several `Microsoft.Extensions.*` libraries with version `>= 8.0.0` which seems to conflict with .NET 7 dependencies for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` used in the project (or upgrade the target framework to .NET 8).